# R Convert a named vector with repeated names to a dataframe

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, frame

I have a vector with repeated names, I want to convert it to a dataframe with each repeated name being an individual column. I have a solution but surely R provides a cleaner way?

```
#Example Input: x
x <- c(1,2,3,4,3,5,6,7)
names(x) <- c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b")

#Desired Output: x.desired
x.desired <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2))
names(x.desired) <- c("a","b")
x.desired$a <- c(1, 3, 3, 6)
x.desired$b <- c(2, 4, 5, 7)

#Using data frame cast (doesn't work)
x.wrong <- data.frame(x)

#My solution, surely there is a cleaner way? I.e. a one line solution
colNames <- unique(names(x))
x.correct <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(x)/length(colNames), ncol=length(colNames)))
names(x.correct) <- colNames
for (i in 1:length(colNames))
    x.correct[,colNames[i]] <- x[which(names(x) == colNames[i])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` by the `names` into a `list` and `cbind`

```
do.call(cbind, split(x, names(x)))
```

Or use `data.frame`

```
data.frame(split(x, names(x)))
```